# Instance methods use

Tags: python-3.x

I define a class like this:

```
class foo1():
    def a():
        pass 
    def b():
        pass 
    def c():
        pass
```

and I create two instances of class foo1:

```
f1 = foo1()
f2 = foo1()
```

now try to print some information of methods:

```
print("f1.a@" , f1.a)
print("f1.b@" , f1.b)
print("f1.c@" , f1.c)

print('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

print("f2.a@" , f2.a)
print("f2.b@" , f2.b)
print("f2.c@" , f2.c)
```

and what happen?

```
f1.a@ <bound method foo1.a of <__main__.foo1 object at 0x10217d128>>
f1.b@ <bound method foo1.b of <__main__.foo1 object at 0x10217d128>>
f1.c@ <bound method foo1.c of <__main__.foo1 object at 0x10217d128>>
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
f2.a@ <bound method foo1.a of <__main__.foo1 object at 0x10217d160>>
f2.b@ <bound method foo1.b of <__main__.foo1 object at 0x10217d160>>
f2.c@ <bound method foo1.c of <__main__.foo1 object at 0x10217d160>>
```

so why for a instance of class foo1, all methods of it is at the same address?

Comment: Isn't it the addresses of the objects? method .. of .. object at ADDRESS

Comment: I made a big mistake, thanks for help.